# Agregar Campo de Búsqueda

Tags: javascript, html, html5, web, aplicación-web

Hola buenas noches/dia!

Srs necesito su apoyo por favor, soy nuevo en lo que es Web, estoy dando mis primeros pasos.
Necesito implementar um campo de búsqueda que haga lo mismo que el CONTROL F.
Se puede realizar solo con html5 o hay que usar javascript?

Tengo una pagina web con un glosario con letras de la A a Z, todo hecho en HTML ( sin backend y base datos ), donde todas las letras estan en 1 sola pagina web.

Necesito agregar el campo de búsqueda para que el usuario no tenga que hacer control f . Me pueden ayudar por favor? Gracias!

Código HTML :
{

```
<p>Form com pesquisa animada:</p>

<form>
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

}

Comment: Hola Rodrigo! ¿Podrías mostrarnos que has intentado?

Comment: La verdad es que notengo el codigo aqui en mi equipo ademas que todo lo que intente buscando con google no resulto. Me puedes dar una luz con codigo porfa?

Comment: Hola amigo.... deje el código HTML, no coloque lo que es css3 ya que considero que no sea necesario.
El contenido de las palabras que deben ser buscadas están en  26 Tablas ( cada una de 100 filas y 4 columnas ) las cuales están en diccionario.html.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el control DataTables de Jquery: https://datatables.net/

De esta forma, montas una tabla HTML con los datos, pones el plugin con el soporte de buscar habilitado y no tienes que programar nada. Sería algo así:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Datatables</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="example" class="display" data-page-length="25" data-order="[[ 1, &quot;asc&quot; ]]" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th data-orderable="false">Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                    <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>46</td>
                    <td>2011/03/09</td>
                    <td>$324,050</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Unity Butler</td>
                    <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>47</td>
                    <td>2009/12/09</td>
                    <td>$85,675</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                    <td>Office Manager</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>51</td>
                    <td>2008/12/16</td>
                    <td>$164,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                    <td>Secretary</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>41</td>
                    <td>2010/02/12</td>
                    <td>$109,850</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                    <td>Financial Controller</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>62</td>
                    <td>2009/02/14</td>
                    <td>$452,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                    <td>Office Manager</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>37</td>
                    <td>2008/12/11</td>
                    <td>$136,200</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                    <td>Director</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>65</td>
                    <td>2008/09/26</td>
                    <td>$645,750</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                    <td>Support Engineer</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>64</td>
                    <td>2011/02/03</td>
                    <td>$234,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>38</td>
                    <td>2011/05/03</td>
                    <td>$163,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                    <td>Support Engineer</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>37</td>
                    <td>2009/08/19</td>
                    <td>$139,575</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Thor Walton</td>
                    <td>Developer</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2013/08/11</td>
                    <td>$98,540</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                    <td>Support Engineer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>47</td>
                    <td>2009/07/07</td>
                    <td>$87,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                    <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>64</td>
                    <td>2012/04/09</td>
                    <td>$138,575</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>2010/01/04</td>
                    <td>$125,250</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>56</td>
                    <td>2012/06/01</td>
                    <td>$115,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                    <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>43</td>
                    <td>2013/02/01</td>
                    <td>$75,650</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>46</td>
                    <td>2011/12/06</td>
                    <td>$145,600</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>47</td>
                    <td>2011/03/21</td>
                    <td>$356,250</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#example').DataTable();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Agradezco su ayuda!
Infelizmente no estoy autorizado a agregar plugin, debe ser todo con html5 o javascript

Comment: Eso es javascript, solo que en lugar de programarlo tu desde cero, aprovechas el código de otros.... no veo el problema. Si quieres hacerlo tu sin plugins, es más complicado y no puedo pasarte el código completo aquí, mejor intenta tu algo y nos publicas cualquier parte en la que te atasques.

Comment: Amigo aqui utilizan AngularJs ( Framework de Google) me dicen..... sabes si existe algo que hace lo mismo en ese Framework? 
Sorry pero no soy programador Web, mis nociones de programación son muy basicas.

Comment: Si no voy errado, AngularJS funciona perfectamente con DataTables.

Comment: Amigo, trate de realizer el código arriba y solo aparecio el listado de las palabras pero sin tabla ni el filtro :S , sabes que puede ser?

Comment: Cierto, hay un error, corrijo la respuesta y ya te funcionará

Comment: Agregue esto en la tag <head> y funciono:
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

Comment: Necesito deshabilitar el show entry y las páginas Previas....

Comment: Ya consegui ..... jajajjajajaa y nunca habia trabajado con javascript xD